# spider graphic line in plotly.graph_objects

Tags: django, plotly, python-3.6

When I generate my chart, the line does not end, however, and I tried in many ways, but nothing worked for me.

what is in r, are some variables that I have declared with already defined values

```
fig = go.Figure()


fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
    name = "Ideal",
    r=[ ideal_Funciones_Responsabilidades, ideal_etapas_propias, ideal_Aspectos_Legales, ideal_Gestion_Ambiental, ideal_Gestion_de_Seguridad, 
    ideal_manejo_Informacion, hallado_Tecnicos, ideal_Humanos , ideal_transversales],
    theta=categories,

    #connectgaps=True,
    #line_color = 'darkviolet'   

    type= 'scatterpolar',
    mode = 'lines',


))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
    name = "Hallado",
    r=[ hallado_Funciones_Responsabilidades, hallado_etapas_propias, hallado_Aspectos_Legales, hallado_Gestion_Ambiental, hallado_Gestion_de_Seguridad, 
    hallado_manejo_Informacion, hallado_Tecnicos, hallado_Humanos, hallado_transversales],
    theta=categories,
    #mode = "markers",


    type= 'scatterpolar',
    mode = 'lines',
    #line_color = 'peru'




))




fig.update_layout(

    polar=dict(


        radialaxis=dict(

            #visible=True,
            range=[0, maximo_valor + 1]
        )

        ),
    #line_close=True,
    # showlegend=False
)
```

[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3btRt.png)

[image]

I will be attentive to your help with this topic.

Comment: Please, ask your question in English

Comment: I removed the matplotlib tag, because the code is unrelated to matplotlib. Use the tag for the language/library you're working with instead.

Comment: @josericardo How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can close the line using `go.Scatterpolar()` by repeating the first element in both the list for r and theta at the end of the list.

Say you declared:

```
r_list=[ ideal_Funciones_Responsabilidades, ideal_etapas_propias, ideal_Aspectos_Legales, ideal_Gestion_Ambiental, ideal_Gestion_de_Seguridad, 
ideal_manejo_Informacion, hallado_Tecnicos, ideal_Humanos , ideal_transversales]
r_list.append(r_list[0])
```

Then use

```
r=r_list
```